# Chartjs area background color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, chart.js

[image: colorful graph background]

How to change the chart area background color using chart js?
I want my chart looks like this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a plugin to fill the canvas.
Below a sample with fixed colors.

You can also have a look to the CHart.js sample: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/plugins/quadrants.html

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const plugin = {
  id: 'bgColorArea',
  beforeDraw(chart, args, options) {
    const {ctx, chartArea: {left, top, width, bottom}, scales: {x, y}} = chart;
    const endTop = y.getPixelForValue(35);
    const endMid = y.getPixelForValue(10);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'lightCoral';
    ctx.fillRect(left, top, width, endTop - top);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'lightGreen';
    ctx.fillRect(left, endTop, width, endMid - endTop);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'lightGrey';
    ctx.fillRect(left, endMid, width, bottom - endMid);
    ctx.restore();
  }
};
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   plugins: [plugin],
   data: {
     labels: ['January', 'Fabruary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
     datasets: [{
       label: 'test',
       data: [50, 35, 45, 47, 10, 3, 27],
       borderWidth: 2,
       borderColor: 'black'
     }]
   }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using this is react js but my chart only gets loaded for the first time. If any state of the website is changed then I'm not able to see the chart again